# connected laptop with TV- sound from tv not working

Tags: laptop, audio, hdmi, ubuntu-12.04, tv

I have connected a tv via HDMI to a laptop running ubuntu 12.  I can see the video on the televsion but the sound plays from the laptop and not from the television.  Any ideas on what I need to change (I checked the sound settings on my laptop and was not sure if I had to turn anything off or on).  Any ideas on what I need to modify to make this work (the sound for the television is not set to mute).

I did not find any settings in particular for HDMI output in the sound settings (the output settings has the volume turned on - I tried by turning it off as well but it did not change anything).

thanks in advance